# Get directories count of IPFS

Tags: api, go, ipfs

I installed the `ipfs version 0.8.0` on WSL Ubuntu 18.04. Started ipfs using `sudo ipfs daemon`. Added 2 directories using the command `sudo ipfs add -r /home/user/ipfstest`, it results like this:

> added QmfYH2KVxANPA3um1W5MYWA6zR4Awv8VscaWyhhQBVj65L ipfstest/abc.sh
> added QmTXny9ZjuFPm4C4KbQSEYxvUp2MYbSCLppPQirW7ap4Go ipfstest

Likewise, I added one more directory having 2 files. Now, I need the total files and directories in my ipfs using `go-ipfs-api`. Following is my code:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "context"
        "os"
        "net/http"
        "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
        "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp"
        "github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs-api"
)

var sh *shell.Shell

func main() {
        sh := shell.NewShell("localhost:5001")
        dir,err:=sh.FilesLs(context.TODO(),"")
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error: %s", err)
                os.Exit(1)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Dir are: %d", dir)

        pins,err:=sh.Pins()
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error: %s", err)
                os.Exit(1)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Pins are: %d", len(pins))
        dqfs_pincount.Add(float64(len(pins)))
        prometheus.MustRegister(dqfs_pincount)
        http.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.Handler())
        http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)
}
```

If I run this code, I get the output as:

```
Dir are: [824634392256] Pins are: 18
```

Pinned files are incremented as I added files. But what is this output `[824634392256]`? And why only one?

I tried giving a path to the function `dir,err:=sh.FilesLs(context.TODO(),"/.ipfs")`. As I guess the files and dir's must be stored in `~/.ipfs`. But this gives an error:

```
error: files/ls: file does not exist
```

How can I get all directories of ipfs? Where I am mistaken? what path should I prove as a parameter? Please help and guide.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit to unpack here.

## Why are you using `sudo`?

IPFS is meant to be run as a regular user. Generally you don't want to run it as root, but you'd instead run the same commands, just without `sudo`:

```sh
ipfs daemon
ipfs add -r /home/user/ipfstest
...
```

## Code doesn't compile

Let's begin with the code, and make sure that's working as intended before moving forward, first off your import:

```golang
"github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs-api"
```

Should read:

```golang
shell "github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs-api"
```

As otherwise the code won't compile, because of your usage of `shell` later in the code.

## Why does `dir` produce the output it does?

Next, let's look at your usage of `dir`. You're storing  `*[]MfsLsEntry` ([MfsLsEntry](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs-api?utm_source=godoc#MfsLsEntry)), which is a slice of pointers. You're outputting that with string formatting `%d`, which will be a base10 integer ([docs](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing)), so the "824634392256" is just the memory address of the `MfsLsEntry` object in the first index of the slice.

## Why does `sh.FilesLs(context.TODO(),"/.ipfs")` fail?

Well `FilesLs` isn't querying your own regular filesystem that your OS runs on, but actually [MFS](https://docs.ipfs.io/concepts/file-systems/#mutable-file-system-mfs). MFS *is* stored locally though, but using the [add API](https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/http/api/#api-v0-add) doesn't automatically add something to your MFS. You can use [FilesCp](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs-api?utm_source=godoc#Shell.FilesCp) to add a CID to your MFS after you `add` it though.

## How do I list my directories on IPFS?

This is a bit of a tricky question. The only data really retain on IPFS is either data pinned, or data referenced in the MFS. So above we already learned the `FilesLs` command lists the files/directories on your MFS. To list your recursive pins (directories), it's quite simple using the command line:

```sh
ipfs pin ls -t recursive
```

For the API though, you'll first want to call something like [Shell.Pins()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs-api?utm_source=godoc#Shell.Pins), filter out for the pins you want (maybe a quick scan through, pull out anything recursive), then query the CIDs using [Shell.ObjectStat](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs-api?utm_source=godoc#Shell.ObjectStat) or whatever you prefer.

If working with the pins though, do remember that it won't feel quite like a regular mutable filesystem, because it isn't. It's much easier to navigate through CIDs added to MFS. So that's how I'd recommend you list your directories on IPFS.